# Images load on each other masonry-filter

Tags: javascript, html, masonry

```
$('.item-filter').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selector = $(this).data('filter');
    $(".item-filter a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

     $(".item").not(selector).hide ();  
     $('.masonry-list').masonry();
     $(selector).show () 
};
```

Images load over each other..
it doesnt load it when i do not click it twice 
..  dualgroup.org/arcadis/projects.html here u can check it 
just the first time when u filter it loads the images right . without click it twice it doesnt load ??

Comment: do i have to change something in style.css or in the  scripts.js

Comment: There is an images loaded option you need to pass into your config

Comment: in my style.css or ??

Comment: Masonry plugin options

Answer (score 0):

i have figured it out
I have change the javascript code to this

```
    /*-- MASONRY --*/
var getMasonry = $('.masonry-list');
getMasonry.imagesLoaded(function () {
    getMasonry.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-sizer',


        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        isAnimated: true
```